# Dynamic settingslogic settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, settingslogic

I'm using the [settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) gem in my Rails app (Ruby 2.0.0p247 / Rails 3.2.13).

I can dynamically change a setting when it is not nested e.g.

```
#config/settings.yml
defaults:&defaults
  mysetting: 1
  nested:
    myothersetting: 2

Settings[:mysetting] = 10
Settings.mysetting # puts 10
```

But I am unable to change a nested attribute in the same way:

```
Settings[:nested][:myothersetting] = 20
Settings.nested.myothersetting # puts 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of ruby & rails you're using, but I tried using a similar setup as your yaml file and was presented with an error about bad parsing. I think that a key which has something nested underneath it cannot also have a value.

That said, I experienced similar behavior - the hash-based accessor for nested values set/returned the expected values while the method-based accessor returned the value from the file and did not get the updates:

```
# config/settings.yml
defaults: &defaults
  thing1: 1
  thing2: 2
  nest:
    thing3: 3

development:
  <<: *defaults

2.0.0p247 :001 > Settings[:nest][:thing3] = 30
 => 30
2.0.0p247 :002 > Settings[:nest][:thing3]
 => 30
2.0.0p247 :003 > Settings.nest.thing3
 => 3
```

It looks like this could be a bug in the gem, which based on the issue list on github seems to be one of many with nested attributes.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I had the nesting wrong in my question - sorry about that. But your answer confirms my observation. I'll file a bug on github.

Comment: The bug report is in https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic/issues/57 . In meantime there is a comment with a solution/workaround: `Settings.nest[:thing3] = 30`